# Loop to create create map from different data subsets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a loop so that I can plot multiple maps showing different areas of the city separately.

I import the data and shapefile as follows:

```
data = read.csv('NAME.csv')
geo = read_sf("NAME.shp")
```

Then, I subset for the area that I want and then merge with the two datasets

```
geo1 = subset(geo, geo$ladnm == "area1")
data_map = merge(geo1, data, by = "variable")
```

Then, I build the map (1 area, across multiple years)

```
map = ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = data_map, aes(fill = V1), color=NA)+ 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#56B1F7", high = "#132B43") +
  facet_wrap(~year)
```

I was hoping there was a way of doing this for each area separately (keeping the year facet) using an R loop function (i.e., versus rerunning this separately 30 times for each area)?